# In R, can I update a column and also create a new one in a single pass?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to see if I can update an `R` dataframe by updating one field and creating another field, so two fields total, in a single pass/line.

I tried the following:
`field1` is the field to update and already exists, while `field2` is the field that would be newly created.

```
df[field1, field2] <- cbind(" added text", "newfield")
```

But since field2 doesn't exist, I'm getting the error: `object 'field2' not found`.

I know of obviously assigning it manually in two steps via the following, but I want to avoid spaghetti code, since I have to repeat for quite a few fields:

```
df$field1[df$field1 == "Original"] <- "Original added text"
df$field2 <- "newfield"
```

Comment: Why not give us a completely reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `purr`:

```
sample_df<-iris
sample_df$Species<- NULL

library(purrr)

walk2(.x = list(Species=iris$Species,
          Sepal.Length=sample_df$Sepal.Length*100),
      .y = c("Species", "Sepal.Length"),
      function(x,y) {sample_df[y]<<-x})

sample_df
```

The logic here is to pass the content of the variables and the names of the variables as separate argumetns which are combine using one as reference and the other as content.

If your are doing this recurrently in your code I would suggest to use `mutate` from the `dplyr` package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `data.table`. Try out:

```
df <- iris
df$Species <- as.character(df$Species)
# let's say that Species is the field to update and already exists,  
# while Species2 is the field that would be newly created
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Species == "setosa",
          c("Species", "Species2") := list("Original added text",
                                           "Species2")][]
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this, but looks like it goes through the entire data frame, so it instantiates that new field `Species2` with the value `Species2`. Is there a way to set it for just that particular row in the data frame?

Comment: Sure, but the other rows will have missing values ! Code edited (you should have a look at [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html))

Comment: `df[Species == "setosa", Species := "Original added text"][, field2 := "newfield"]` updates only the filtered column while adding a new column filled with a value for each row...